# onChildClick events stop after scrolling a listview

Tags: android

I have an app that uses an ExpandableListView widget filled with items via a BaseExpandableListAdapter. The app was built for the Android Version 1.6, and when I test it using the Android Emulator (version 1.6 build) everything works fine. I can scroll the list up and down and when I tap on any items in the list I get a onChildClick() event.

However, when I try to run this same app on an real Android phone (running Gingerbread), I only get onChildClick() events if I don't scroll the ExpandableListView. If I scroll the list too much, I no longer get onChildClick events (nor itemClickEvents also).

So I'm baffled. Why do I not get any onChild or onItem click events for the listview items after I scroll it? Note, that if I scroll it just a small amount (say, 2 or three lines) I do get click events, but any more scrolling and then I no longer get click events for any item in the list.

Any suggestions or advice would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

Ok, I'm answering my own question here for others who may have the same problem. The issue I'm experiencing seems to be related to the focus status of the ExpandableListView Widget. When I scroll the list, the ListView widget seems to lose focus and I can't select any of the listed items. I'm not sure what the best way is to correct this, but I did get this to work.

I added a scroll listener for the ListView widget as show:

```
getExpandableListView().setOnScrollListener(this);
```

I then added a method to my activity that would set the focus back to the ListView Widget once it is finished scrolling:

```
@Override
public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView view, int scrollState) 
{   
    // - this method is called when there is a scroll event in the main ExpandableListView widget.

    // - after the user stops scrolling the listview, make sure to set the focus to the widget

    if ( scrollState == OnScrollListener.SCROLL_STATE_IDLE )
    {
       ExpandableListView elv = getExpandableListView();
   elv.requestFocusFromTouch();
    }
}
```

Now that seems to fix my issue. I'm sure there's a better way (and if you know of one, please post it here), otherwise my "hack" seems to work ok.

Hope it helps someone with a similar issue.

Comment: this has been really helpful to me..just debugged mine..thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

Thanks, this answer solved my problem on losing focus on  while scrolling.

```
ListView mRecentSearchList;

mRecentSearchList.setOnScrollListener(new OnScrollListener(){
                        public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem, int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {

                            //adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                        }
                        public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView view, int scrollState) {

                            //adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                          if(scrollState == OnScrollListener.SCROLL_STATE_IDLE ||scrollState == SCROLL_STATE_TOUCH_SCROLL || scrollState == SCROLL_STATE_FLING) 
                          {
                              mRecentSearchList.requestFocusFromTouch();

                          }
                        }
                      });
```

Comment: @Stephan (wasn't me) - another question might be: why isn't formatting easier ;-) The code contains tabs which ctrl-K can't cope with ...

Comment: @kleopatra One simple solution : Ask Eclipse guys to make a web module with their Java Code Editor ^^

Comment: This solution worked for me whereas the one from cohoman didn't.

Answer (score 0):

I have experienced exactly the same problem and I found that it was caused not by list itself but adapter(ResourceCursorTreeAdapter). To prevent groups to collapse I was doing a hack as follows in my adapter:

```
@Override
    public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View view = super.getGroupView(groupPosition, isExpanded, convertView, parent);
        ExpandableListView list = (ExpandableListView) parent;
        list.expandGroup(groupPosition);
        return view;
    }
```

If you do the same, please try replacing this with different solution.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I've used the same solution proposed by [cohoman](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6659290), however the requestFocus() method provided me a better user experience:

```
  navList.setOnScrollListener(new OnScrollListener()
  {

     @Override
     public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView view, int scrollState)
     {
        if(scrollState == OnScrollListener.SCROLL_STATE_IDLE)
        {
            navList.requestFocus();
        }
     }

     @Override
     public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem, int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount)
     {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

     }
  });
```